# JavaScript: Keep multiple instances of javascript objects from disposing after completion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, dispose

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.container').ready(function() {

        var v = new Video($(this));
        v.load();

    });

});
```

How can I keep v from disposing itself? The initialized class loads 3 variables: `video`, `source` and `controls`. When a click or event listener calls its function and tries to access any of them it cannot, because they have since been destroyed.

How can I get around this problem?

More sample code:

```
$.Class('Video', {
    init: function(container) {
        this.video = container.find('.video');
        this.source = this.video[0];
        this.controls = {
            // ...
            total: container.find('.total'),
            buffered: container.find('.buffered')
        };
    },
    load: function() {
        this.source.addEventListener('progress', function() {
            var buffered = Math.floor(this.source.buffered.end(0)) / Math.floor(this.source.duration);
            this.controls.buffered.width(Math.floor(buffered * this.controls.total.width()));
        }, false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in JavaScript are function scoped, so when the callback function passed to   $('.container').ready() exits, the variable you declared in that function, v, is out-of-scope and eligible for garbage collection.

One way to avoid that is to declare a global variable and store your Video object in that. For example:

```
var v;  // Global, because it is declared outside any function
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').ready(function() {
        v = new Video($(this));
        v.load();
    });
});
```

Of course, global variables are at least as much trouble in JavaScript as in any other language (maybe more). A best-practice is to declare exactly one global variable, an object, for your entire page/application and store any and all of your persistent data within that object. You want to give this lone global a name that is likely to be unique, so that it won't conflict with any third-party scripts you may use. I like to use the convention used with Java namespaces of using a registered domain name associated with the work as the unique identifier. So if you or your employer owns the domain name examplename.com:

```
if (! window.examplename) {
    window.examplename = {};
}
examplename.videos = [];

...

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').ready(function() {
        var v = new Video($(this));
        v.load();
        examplename.videos.push(v);
    });
});
```

Elsewhere in your code, access the video objects like so:

```
$.each(examplename.videos, function(idx, vid) {
        vid.someMethod();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep references around.  You should have an app namespace and store model object in it.

```
window.App = {}; // global object literal acting as a cache lookup

App[video.id] = video; // store the object when its created.
```

if you do that, you can always lookup the objects by id (or some other identifying parameter). If you only need to keep this one object around, just put it on the global scope by removing the `var` from its declaration.

Comment: Why should you have an app namespace?

Comment: It prevents polluting the entire global namespace with random objects.  It keeps everything related to your application in one spot.

Comment: I get the same `TypeError` as before saying the code within the eventlistener functions cannot access `this.source` or `this.controls`.

Comment: did you initialize `Videos`?  Also, I don't see any code in your example where you touch `this.source` or `this.controls`, so I can't really speak to that.  Seems like an unrelated problem.

Comment: @hvgotcodes I added the code to the op. You'll see the `this.controls.buffered.width(...);`, that line will error saying 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.controls.buffered').

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function and store them in the `.container`.

```
$(this).data('video', new Video($(this));
```

To read, you can use like below from anywhere

```
$('.container').data('video');
```

**Edit:** Can you try modifying your code like below,

```
$.Class('Video', {
    init: function(container) {
        var video = container.find('.video');
        var source = this.video[0];
        var controls = {
            // ...
            total: container.find('.total'),
            buffered: container.find('.buffered')
        };

        //added code
        container.data('player_props', {'video': video, 'source': source, 'controls': controls});

    },
    load: function() {
        this.source.addEventListener('progress', function() {
            //added code
            var playerProps = $('.container').data('player_props'); 

            //modified referneces of source and control
            var buffered = Math.floor(playerProps['source'].buffered.end(0)) / Math.floor(playerProps['source'].duration);
            this.controls.buffered.width(Math.floor(buffered * playerProps['controls'].total.width()));
        }, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('.container')` is a class for a reason, it's so I can have multiple videos at once. What happens if I have 3 videos and I call load, it's going to look up all 3 and do something wrong.

Comment: The idea is to store the video/source/control in the .container element. Of course You can still store more than one information with different key (player_prop_0,  player_prop_1, and so on..) and read them accordingly in your load function. You will have to implement the same logic if you going to store this in a var that is in global scope.

Comment: On the side note, your init will be fine because you pass the specific container element (not a whole bunch of container(s)).. So the video/source/controls inside that container will be associated with that specific container. I am not sure how you call load function, but It will work fine, if you can pass specific container as an argument to the load function.

Answer (score 0):

Using var declares the variable as local.  Drop that and you should be okay...

```
v = new Video($(this));
```

Comment: This will work, but be aware that you implicitly declaring a global variable named v.

Comment: If I drop the var's inside the class, will those 3 objects be global within that class, or can I have multiple instances with different globals?

Comment: Are video, source and controls members of v, or separate variables?  If they're separate variables then they're being created by the Video object which means that script is responsible for their scope.

Comment: @Archer video, source and controls are loaded using `this.video = ...;`, etc.

Comment: In that case they could be accessed by v.video, v.source and v.controls

Comment: @Archer the problem isn't accessing them from within the `$('.container').ready()` scope, it's accessing them within the instance of `Video`.

Comment: @BrianGraham within Video, if you used var in the init method then they would only be accessible in that method.  Since you don't use var in there then they should be accessible in any method in the Video class.

Comment: @Archer and they are, until the end of `$('.container').ready()`. I want them to last until the page reloads.

Comment: They will only be disposed when their parent is disposed, which in this case is v.  That is disposed when the ready method is completed because of the use of var, which makes v local to the ready method.  Removing that var will make v global so it's still alive after the ready method ends.  You can then access anything in it with v.name, anywhere in your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an object to stay alive, then it needs to be accessible from a scope that can still be reached.  For example, you could assign v as a property of a global object.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a javascript variable is bound to the function it is declared in (i.e. where `var` is.  If there is no `var`, then it is in global scope.

So the question is not really how to stop it being disposed, but how you can  ensure that it is accessible where you want it.

If you want it to be accessible absolutely everywhere (hint: you probably don't, global variables in javascript are a common source of error), then simply remove `var`.

If you want it to be available to the rest of the function called by `$(document).ready`, then moving `var v`, thus, will do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var v;
    $('.container').ready(function() {

        v = new Video($(this));
        v.load();

    });

});
```

A common technique is to use an anonymous function to create a wider scope for any variables that you want to be accessible from multiple functions, without making them completely global, thus:

```
(function(){
     var v, f0, f1;

     f0 = function (){
       v = 1;
     };

     f1 = function (){
       v += 1;
     };
}());
```

Comment: In your first example, won't v go out of scope as soon as the outer ready callback has exited?

Comment: @dgvid:  Yes.  That is why the preceding paragraph says "If you want it to be available to the rest of the function called by $(document).ready".